# Concourse CI / Gradle : Failed to create parent directory

Tags: gradle, concourse

I'm trying to build a java project with gradle `3.4.1` and concourse using the vagrant `concourse/lite` box (`v2.7.4`) and the docker image `gradle/3.4.1-jdk8`

My `pipeline.yml` is

```
---
resources:
  - name: devoxx-talks-src
    type: git
    check_every: 1m
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/pomverte/devoxx-talks
      branch: concourse-ci

jobs:
  - name: devoxx-talks-build
    plan:
      - get: devoxx-talks-src
        trigger: true
      - task: devoxx-talks-gradle
        file: devoxx-talks-src/ci/task-gradle.yml
```

`task-gradle.yml` :

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: gradle
    tag: '3.4.1-jdk8'

inputs:
- name: devoxx-talks-src

run:
  path: sh
  dir: devoxx-talks-src
  args:
  - -exc
  - |
    gradle --stacktrace build
```

Here is the error I get :

```
+ gradle --stacktrace build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create parent directory '/tmp/build/76b9d33d/devoxx-talks-src/.gradle' when creating directory '/tmp/build/76b9d33d/devoxx-talks-src/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create parent directory '/tmp/build/76b9d33d/devoxx-talks-src/.gradle' when creating directory '/tmp/build/76b9d33d/devoxx-talks-src/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup'
    at org.gradle.util.GFileUtils.mkdirs(GFileUtils.java:313)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:52)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:30)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:89)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:63)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.cleanup.DefaultBuildOutputCleanupCache.createCache(DefaultBuildOutputCleanupCache.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.cleanup.DefaultBuildOutputCleanupCache.cleanIfStale(DefaultBuildOutputCleanupCache.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.cleanup.BuildOutputCleanupListener.onConfigure(BuildOutputCleanupListener.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.onConfigure(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:239)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuildAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:160)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.819 secs
```

Does anyone know why Gradle can't create the parent directory ?

Should I setup a `settings.gradle` file may be ?

Answer (score 7):

The gradle image sets the user to `gradle`, which doesn't have the necessary rights to create a new directory. Set the user to `root` in your task as a quick fix.

`task-gradle.yml`:

```
…

run:
  user: root
  path: sh
  dir: devoxx-talks-src
  args:
  - -exc
  - |
    gradle --stacktrace build
```

Comment: that fixed it thanks! any idea how to add gradle as a user to concourse and eliminate the ned to use root?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this error, in Jenkins, by running Gradle with the `--no-daemon` switch:

```java
withGradle {
  pwsh label: 'Groovy unit tests with Gradle and JenkinsPipelineUnit', script: './gradlew test --quiet --no-daemon'
}
```

It has the added benefit of killing the daemon when it's done, which I was finding I was having to do manually: `./gradlew test; ./gradlew --stop`

I had also tried changing the user the JVM was using, as implied above:
`./gradlew test --system-prop user.name=myusername`. But it didn't change anything when I also used `--no-daemon` and took out the `--system-prop`.