# concourse gradle java build CI

Tags: docker, gradle, vert.x, concourse

I am attempting to make a concourse CI pipeline for a java / gradle (vertx) build.

I am getting similar error when using the gradle docker image to run the build from concourse or when running locally (directly using the same docker image)

```
PS D:\Development\github\vertx-concourse-gradle> docker run --rm -v .:/project -w /project  gradle:3.4-jdk8 gradle build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to create parent directory '/project/.gradle' when creating directory '/project/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.924 secs
```

seemed to be issue with permission or the fact my sources are on windows 10.

here is the repo I am building and running the build for

https://github.com/gadieichhorn/vertx-concourse-gradle

Comment: fixed my own issue with adding an output folder and using root as user,

Comment: see this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880832/concourse-ci-gradle-failed-to-create-parent-directory

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and file permissions was the issue. I my case I was creating a new user in docker image instead of using root. And this new user did not have permissions to create the folder.